# What does dtype=object mean while creating a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, types

I was experimenting with numpy arrays and created a numpy array of strings:

```py
ar1 = np.array(['avinash', 'jay'])
```

As I have read from from their official guide, operations on numpy array are propagated to individual elements. So I did this:

```py
ar1 * 2
```

But then I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-aaac6331c572> in <module>()
----> 1 ar1 * 2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

But when I used `dtype=object`

```py
ar1 = np.array(['avinash', 'jay'], dtype=object)
```

while creating the array I am able to do all operations.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

NumPy arrays are stored as contiguous blocks of memory. They usually have a single datatype (e.g. integers, floats or fixed-length strings) and then the bits in memory are interpreted as values with that datatype.

Creating an array with `dtype=object` is different. The memory taken by the array now is filled with *pointers* to Python objects which are being stored *elsewhere* in memory (much like a Python `list` is really just a list of pointers to objects, not the objects themselves).

Arithmetic operators such as `*` don't work with arrays such as `ar1` which have a `string_` datatype (there are special functions instead - see below). NumPy is just treating the bits in memory as characters and the `*` operator doesn't make sense here. However, the line

```
np.array(['avinash','jay'], dtype=object) * 2
```

works because now the array is an array of (pointers to) Python strings. The `*` operator is well defined for these Python string objects. New Python strings are created in memory and a new `object` array with references to the new strings is returned.

---

If you have an array with `string_` or `unicode_` dtype and want to repeat each string, you can use `np.char.multiply`:

```
In [52]: np.char.multiply(ar1, 2)
Out[52]: array(['avinashavinash', 'jayjay'], 
      dtype='<U14')
```

NumPy has many other [vectorised string methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html) too.

Comment: do you know if there are any efficiency gains to be had when doing an operation on an object array vs trying to iterate through the a python list?

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's `str` dtype and its operations are not optimized, so it's probably best to stick to using `object` dtype when working with strings with numpy.

##### `str` consumes more memory than `object`

Depending on the length of the fixed-length string and the size of the array, the ratio differs but as long as the longest string in the array is longer than 2 characters, `str` consumes more memory (they are equal when the longest string in the array is 2 characters long). For example, in the following example, `str` consumes almost 8 times more memory.

```py
from pympler.asizeof import asizesof

ar1 = np.array(['this is a string', 'string']*1000, dtype=object)
ar2 = np.array(['this is a string', 'string']*1000, dtype=str)
asizeof(ar2) / asizeof(ar1)  # 7.944444444444445
```

##### `str` is slower than `object`

Numpy's vectorized string methods are not optimized, so operating on the `object` array is often faster. For example, in the example in the OP where each character is repeated, a simple `*` (aka `multiply()`) is not only more concise but also over 10 times faster than `char.multiply()`.

```py
import timeit
setup = "import numpy as np; from __main__ import ar1, ar2"
t1 = min(timeit.repeat("ar1*2", setup, number=1000))
t2 = min(timeit.repeat("np.char.multiply(ar2, 2)", setup, number=1000))
t2 / t1   # 10.650433758517027
```

Even for functions that cannot be readily be applied on the array, instead of the vectorized `char` method of `str` arrays, it is faster to loop over the `object` array and work on the Python strings.

For example, iterating over the `object` array and calling `str.count()` on each Python string is over 3 times faster than the vectorized `char.count()` on the `str` array.

```py
f1 = lambda: np.array([s.count('i') for s in ar1])
f2 = lambda: np.char.count(ar2, 'i')

setup = "import numpy as np; from __main__ import ar1, ar2, f1, f2, f3"
t3 = min(timeit.repeat("f1()", setup, number=1000))
t4 = min(timeit.repeat("f2()", setup, number=1000))

t4 / t3   # 3.251369161574832
```

On a side note, if it comes to explicit loop, iterating over a list is faster than iterating over a numpy array. So in the previous example, a further performance gain can be made by iterating over the list

```py
f3 = lambda: np.array([s.count('i') for s in ar1.tolist()])
#                                               ^^^^^^^^^  <--- convert to list here
t5 = min(timeit.repeat("f3()", setup, number=1000))
t3 / t5   # 1.2623498005294627
```