# np.apply_along_axis slices output when used with ' '.join

Tags: python, numpy

.I have a 2D array of strings and I intend to concatenate the strings along each row with a space between them. I used the following code, but it fails with a simple input, but it shouldn't be the case.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', 
               '3','3', '3', '3', '3', '9', '11', '3', '3'],
              ['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', 
               '11', '9', '11', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']])

def concat(x, separator):
    return separator.join(x).strip()

b = np.apply_along_axis(concat, -1, a, ' ')
```

Expected:

```
b = ['3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 9 11 3 3',
     '3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 11 9 11 3 3 3 3 3 3']
```

Output (See the end of the 2nd row of b):

```
b = ['3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 9 11 3 3',
     '3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 11 9 11 3 3 3 3 3 ']
```

The last `3` is missing in the output. Any reason why this should happen?

Comment: Can I please know the reason of the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What does dtype=object mean while creating a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877508/what-does-dtype-object-mean-while-creating-a-numpy-array) to understand why you need to add *dtype=object* to make it work

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Learned something new :)