# Convert a list of lists to numpy array in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists(have tuples inside) and want to convert it to a numpy array.

```
 Input: 
 [[1, 2, 3, (2, 4)], [3, 4, 8, 9], [2, 3, 5, (3, 7)]]
 Expected output:  
 array([[1, 2, 3, (2, 4)], [3, 4, 8, 9], [2, 3, 5, (3, 7)]])
```

I have tried np.array and np.asarray, but it raise an error: setting an array element with a sequence. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: But is `(2, 4)` of `dtype` `int32`?

Comment: oh, i should delete that. dtype is not important for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `dtype` to object.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3, (2, 4)], [3, 4, 8, 9], [2, 3, 5, (3, 7)]], dtype=object)
array([[1, 2, 3, (2, 4)],
       [3, 4, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 5, (3, 7)]], dtype=object)
```

Note that there's probably not a good reason to create this array in the first place. The main strength of numpy is fast operations on flat sequences of numeric data, with `dtype=object` you are storing pointers to full fledged Python objects - just like in a list.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877845/3620003) is a good answer explaining the `object` `dtype`.