# Python pandas - Convert string to datetime without a year using pandas.to_datetime()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe which has timestamps and their datatype is object (string):

```
data_log = pd.read_csv(DATA_LOG_PATH)
print(data_log['LocalTime'])

0      09:38:49 
1      09:38:50 
2      09:38:51 
3      09:38:52 
4      09:38:53
         ...    
Name: LocalTime, Length: 872, dtype: object
```

Now I try to convert to datetime:

```
data_log['LocalTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data_log['LocalTime'], format='%H:%M:%S')
print(data_log['LocalTime'])

0     1900-01-01 09:38:49
1     1900-01-01 09:38:50
2     1900-01-01 09:38:51
3     1900-01-01 09:38:52
4     1900-01-01 09:38:53
              ...        
Name: LocalTime, Length: 872, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How do I remove that date there? I just want the time in the format that I specified, but it adds the 1900-01-01 to every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the time part of a datetime series with `Series.dt.time`

```
print(data_log['LocalTime'].dt.time)
```

This series will consist of Python standard library `datetime.time` objects.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a big confused as to why it still says object as dtype but when I iterate through it and use the python type() function it does say datetime.time. Either way, thanks!

Comment: Dtype object means that the Series is an array containing pointers to python objects. The objects don't even have to be of the same type. Other dtypes are much stricter and can only be used for a single type of data. That means that they can be more memory efficient and vectorized operations can be significantly faster, at the cost of flexibility. The object dtype is a used for python types that has no corresponding numpy type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877508/what-does-dtype-object-mean-while-creating-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways from the datatype with `1900-01-01`:

```
data_log['LocalTime'] = pd.Series([lt.time() for lt in data_log['LocalTime']])
```

or using a lambda function:

```
data_log['LocalTime'] = data_log.LocalTime.apply(lambda x: x.time(), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For check the type in specific columns:

```
print(df['LocalTime'].dtypes)
```

---

**to_dateTime** func from pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

```
df['LocalTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
```

where: **unit='s'** defines the unit of the timestamp (seconds in this case)

For taking consider timezones:

```
df.rimestamp.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Brussels')
```