# Why does my date column change when I convert to an ndarray

Tags: python, timestamp, datetime64

below is my dataframe

```
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [Timestamp('2023-03-14 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2063-03-15 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2043-03-21 00:00:00'),Timestamp('2053-10-09 00:00:00')],
                    'offset' : [1, 9, 8, 1]
})
```

when I convert my 'Year" column to list(), they are saved as time stamp

```
>>> df['Year'].to_list()
[Timestamp('2023-03-14 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2063-03-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2043-03-21 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2053-10-09 00:00:00')]
```

However, when I convert to values they are saved as datetime64

```
>>> df['Year'].values
array(['2023-03-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2063-03-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2043-03-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2053-10-09T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

How do I get my array in `Timestamp` itself (instead of `datetime64` format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's converted to a `datetime64` because numpy arrays only hold [certain datatypes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types). `Timestamp` objects are not one of them. This has to do with how numpy arrays are stored as one contiguous block in memory, and handled by numpy's C-backend.

Starting [v1.7](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html),  core datatypes `datetime64` and `timedelta64` were added to support these functionalities, but they still store data in memory as integers <sup>citation needed</sup>

You can create a numpy array of `Timestamp` objects with `np.array(df.Year.to_list())`, but that will result in an array having `dtype=object`

```
array([Timestamp('2023-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2063-03-15 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2043-03-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2053-10-09 00:00:00')],
      dtype=object)
```

For more information on what this entails, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877845/843953)

> Creating an array with `dtype=object` is different. The memory taken by the array now is filled with pointers to Python objects which are being stored elsewhere in memory (much like a Python list is really just a list of pointers to objects, not the objects themselves).

Comment: prefect! thanks for your explanation @Pranav, that was most helpful