# Combinig two numpy arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, merge

I want to add one `numpy` array two another so it will look like this:

```
a = [3, 4]
b = [[6, 5], [2, 1]]
```

output:

```
[[3, 4], [[6, 5], [2, 1]]]
```

It should look like the output above and not like `[[3,4],[6,5],[2,1]]`.

How do I do that with `numpy` arrays?

Comment: You get `dtype='object'`

Comment: What did you try?  What the `shape` and `dtype` of the desired array?

Answer (score 2):

Work with pure python `list`s, and not `numpy` arrays.

It doesn't make sense to have a `numpy` array holding two `list` objects. There's literally no gain in doing that.

---

If you directly instantiate an array like so:

```
np.array([[3, 4], [[6, 5], [2, 1]]])
```

You get

```
array([[3, 4],
       [list([6, 5]), list([2, 1])]], dtype=object)
```

which is an array with dtype=`object`. Most of numpy's power is lost in this case. For more information on examples and why, take a look [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877508/what-does-dtype-object-mean-while-creating-a-numpy-array).

---

If you work with pure python lists, then you can easily achieve what you want:

```
>>> a + b
[[3, 4], [[6, 5], [2, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy as built-in stack commands that are (in my opinion) slightly easier to use:

```
>>> a = np.array([3, 4])
>>> b = np.array([[6, 5], [2, 1]])
>>> np.row_stack([b, a])
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 5],
       [2, 1]])
```

There's also a column stack.
Ref: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.row_stack.html

Comment: hank you :), but for me it is important that the two arrays will be combined two one array with two entries like: array([[3,4],[[6,5],[2,1]]] and not one array with three entries like you did

Answer (score 0):

You can't stack arrays of different shapes in one array the way you want (or you have to fill in gaps with NaNs or zeroes), so if you want to iterate over them, consider using list.

```
a = np.array([3, 4])
b = np.array([[6, 5], [2, 1]])
c = [a, b]
for arr in c:
    ...
```

If you still want a numpy array, you can try this:

```
>>> a = np.array([3, 4])
>>> b = np.array([[6, 5], [2, 1]])
>>> a.resize(b.shape,refcheck=False)
>>> c = np.array([a, b])

array([[[3, 4],
        [0, 0]],

       [[6, 5],
        [2, 1]]])
```